# Telling if a list contains some information in sequential order

Tags: haskell

Given a list like:

```
let list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I am trying to come up with a way to detect if `7,8,9` exists in the list in sequential order and simply printout 'success' if it does and 'fail' otherwise.

I am trying to accomplish this using `zip` for the index. Can someone advise if I am on the right track or if there is a better way to accomplish this?

```
zip [0..] list
```

And then something like:

```
[if (snd x)== 
             7 && let index = (fst x) 
               && (snd x)==8 && (fst x)==(index+1) 
               && (snd x)==9 && (fst x)==(index+2) 
               then "success" 
               else "fail" | x <- list]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When trying to figure out a list algorithm it's usually best to start by
thinking about the special case in the list head. In this case, how would you
test that the list begins with `[7,8,9]`?

```
beginsWith789 :: [Int] -> Bool
beginsWith789 (7:8:9:_) = True
beginsWith789 _         = False
```

I.e. we can just pattern match to the first three elements. Now to generalize
this, if we don't find the subsequence in the list head, we recursively check
the tail of the list

```
contains789 :: [Int] -> Bool
contains789 (7:8:9:_) = True
contains789 (_:xs)    = contains789 xs
contains789 _         = False
```

Now if we want to further generalize this to find any subsequence, we can use
the `isPrefixOf` function from `Data.List`:

```
import Data.List (isPrefixOf)

contains :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
contains sub lst | sub `isPrefixOf` lst = True
contains (_:xs)  = contains sub xs
contains _       = False
```

We can tidy this up by using `any` and `tails` to check if any successively 
shorter tail of the list begins with the given subsequence:

```
import Data.List (isPrefixOf, tails)

contains :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
contains sub = any (sub `isPrefixOf`) . tails
```

Or, we can simply use the standard library function [`isInfixOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3aisInfixOf). ;)

```
> import Data.List
> [7,8,9] `isInfixOf` [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
True
```

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend the [`isInfixOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:isInfixOf) function from `Data.List`. Finding the sequence is as easy as

```
let hasSequence = [7,8,9] `isInfixOf` list
```

Comment: As always, [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is great for finding these kinds of utility functions when you aren't sure if they exist. In this case we want a function that takes two lists and returns whether one is a sublist of the other. That type signature would be `[a] -> [a] -> Bool`, and indeed when we enter that in Hoogle, `isInfixOf` is at the top of the [results](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+Bool).

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
elemIndex (7,8,9) $ zip3 list (tail list) (tail (tail list))
```

elemIndex is from Data.List.

If you don't care about what index it's at, you can use this

```
elem (7,8,9) $ zip3 list (tail list) (tail (tail list))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you also wanted to count the cases where some elements appear in the given order, but with some other elements between them. Seems like the other answers only count the cases where `[7, 8, 9]` is a sublist of the original. If you want let's say `[7,8,9]` be found in `[7,0,8,0,9,0]`, you could use

```
appears :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
appears [] _ = True
appears _ [] = False
appears ns@(n : ns') (h : hs')
    | n == h    = appears ns' hs'
    | otherwise = appears ns hs'
```

Now

```
appears [7,8,9] [7,0,8,0,9] --> True
appears [7,8,9] [1..10]     -->  True
appears [3,8,9] [1..10]     -->  True
appears [10,8,9] [1..10]    -->  False
```